# Unable to view the Complete and set auto complete options in Azure repo Pull request, even though there is no conflicts

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-repos

Unable to view the Complete and set auto complete options in Azure repo Pull request,  even though there is no conflicts

I can see only mark as draft and abadon

I need to select the Complete and set auto complete option in azure repo PR

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this point:  [Set a pull request to autocomplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/complete-pull-requests?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#set-a-pull-request-to-autocomplete).

> If you don't see Set auto-complete, you don't have any branch
> policies. For more information, see Branch policies.

Try to add some approvers or build validation: [Branch policies and settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)

Answer (score 0):

To complete a PR, you must be a member of the **Contributors** security group in the project the PR is in, or have the corresponding permissions, for example, the **Contribute** permission on your target repo.

To have the "Contribute" permission on your target repo, contact someone with permission to manage the repo permission, such as project admin, set your "Contribute" permission to Allow. Go to Project Settings ->
Repositories -> Click your target repo from the repo list -> Security -> Set "Contribute" permission to **Allow**.
[image]

To have **Set auto-complete** option, as mentioned by Shamrai, you need to have branch policies enabled for your target branch.

See the detailed info about completing PR from official doc [Complete, abandon, or revert pull requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/complete-pull-requests?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser).